# Resize image on a website that can't scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website that the client don't want to scroll so the header and footer is fixed to the top and bottom.

The thing is that image inside the content must resize keeping the same ratio. I have and exemple here

[image]

So the images 1,2 and 3 should stretch keeping it's ratio while the header and footer are fixed where they are. Note that there's a margin of 10px between images inside but not in the outside.

Any clues on how to achieve this ? (CSS or jQuery or both);

Here's a fiddle that I've started quickly to help you play with it : http://jsfiddle.net/2HJuC/2/

Comment: You might be able to use percentages for height or width in CSS styles for the images. These should allow the images to re-size as the page gets re-sized.

Comment: I'm already using the famous width:100%; height:auto... but it's not working very well with website that can't scroll ;)

Comment: would you be able to post any of the code from this page?

Comment: If the header and footer are fixed heights, I think you have to go with jQuery.

Comment: That's why I'm asking the question! How to achieve this ?

Comment: Whenever the page resizes, (Using `$(window).resize();`) resize `#content` to be 100px less than the window height (since the header and footer are both 50px). Now the problem is when the window isn't the same ratio as your set up, what are you going to do? Have it shrink/grow to fit the height or width? You could do what's (roughly) done here: http://vintageamericacollection.com/ (click the 3rd section)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that would do the trick (jquery):

http://jsfiddle.net/2HJuC/5/

That resizes only right images. 
But what happens if user resize window ?

Comment: Just change `$(window).load(function()` with `$(window).on('resize load',function()` in your code, so it will calculate again on...window resize obv. Anyway it doesn't seem to work very well :)

Comment: Yes, its point to start. If you have that layout always (1 left image, and 2 right) it's easier. I will finish it up.

Comment: Nice but as I said the first col should be aligned left without margin-left and same for col right with no margin right. First col should be around 70% width and 30% for the 2nd. Nice work, it gives me a start.

Comment: I made it to resize right and left at 50%, you can rework it.

Answer (score -1):

Try keeping the header and footer at a fixed height/width and absolute location, and use a quick jQuery resize fix like this:

http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/quick-tip-resizing-images-based-on-browser-window-size/

Unfortunately, I don't believe you'll have much luck only using CSS since the website doesn't scroll.